# Dockerhub login works but docker login does not

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I am able to login to DockerHub, but from my linux machine if I run

```
docker login -u DOCKER_USER -p DOCKER_PASS
```

with the same credentials that allow me to login on dockerhub, I get

> Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unauthorized: incorrect username or password

My passworkd contains an exclamation mark that creates me some issues, but enclosing it in single quotes should work, right? Like

```
docker login -u DOCKER_USER -p 'my!pass'
```

What could be the problem? Should I set the `server` argument of `docker login`? If yes, how do I know which server ?

Comment: Are you using 2fa? Are you logging in with an access token or your user password?

Comment: No, just user and password

Comment: Have you tried logging in without the `-p` option and entering the password interactively?

Comment: Does your `DOCKER_USER` include uppercase characters? IIRC the user must be the lowercase equivalent (i.e. `FederioTaschin` would be `federicotaschin`). It's more secure to `DOCKER_PASS="my!pass"; echo ${DOCKER_PASS} | docker login --user ${DOCKER_USER} --password-stdin` to prevent the password being recorded in the shell history.

Comment: @BMitch yes I did and I get the same error

Comment: @DazWilkin yes, my username has uppercase letters. I’ll try the lowercase version as soon as I’m back and let you know

Comment: The username is also part of the repository name in Hub, and repository names cannot have upper case characters.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution: I was using the username with some uppercase letters, which were working when logging in in the DockerHub website but not in the `docker login` command. As usernames are always lowercase, simply writing the username in lowercase letters worked.

I assume the DockerHub website does this conversion automatically, so it was transparent to me